# Using forall in Z3 haskell

Tags: haskell, z3, smt

I'm using `z3` package in haskell, but can't figure out from the documentation how to call `mkForall`

I'm trying to implement this

```
(declare-const a (Array Int Int))
(assert (= (select a 0) 10))
(assert (= (select a 1) 7))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (> (select a x) 5)))
(check-sat)
```

So far I have this

```
do
  intSort <- mkIntSort
  arraySort <- mkArraySort intSort intSort
  a <- mkFreshVar "a" arraySort
  _0 <- mkInteger 0
  _1 <- mkInteger 1
  _10 <- mkInteger 10
  _7 <- mkInteger 7
  _5 <- mkInteger 5
  assert =<< mkEq _10 =<< mkSelect a _0
  assert =<< mkEq _7 =<< mkSelect a _1
  x <- mkStringSymbol "x"
  mkForall [] [x] [intSort] =<< mkLe _5 =<< mkSelect a x
  solverCheck
```

The second last line doesn't work because I don't have the AST where `x Int` is declared

Whats the proper way to do a `mkForall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to `declare-const` for it outside `mkForAll`

```
do
  intSort <- mkIntSort
  arraySort <- mkArraySort intSort intSort
  a <- mkFreshVar "a" arraySort
  _0 <- mkInteger 0
  _1 <- mkInteger 1
  _10 <- mkInteger 10
  _7 <- mkInteger 7
  _5 <- mkInteger 5
  assert =<< mkEq _10 =<< mkSelect a _0
  assert =<< mkEq _7 =<< mkSelect a _1
  x <- mkStringSymbol "x"
  xv <- mkVar x intSort
  -- ^^^^^ note this line
  mkForall [] [x] [intSort] =<< mkLe _5 =<< mkSelect a xv
  solverCheck
```

--- EDIT

my assertion with forall doesnt seem to hold despite doing `assert =<< mkForall ....` i think `xv` does not bind to `x` in the `mkForall` call

---- SOLVED

```
  arg <- mkBound 0 intSort
  assert =<< mkForall [] [x] [intSort] =<< mkLe _5 =<< mkSelect a arg
```

use mkBound to get the deBruijn index argument